# How can I check all checkboxes with one checkbox and add a class to their parent element in React using use-state?

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, react-hooks, react-component

I am trying to do a to-do app and at one point I am completely stuck.

This is my current page so far:
[image]

I am going to explain to you what I am trying to do on the above page in short.

I have ***text input*** in which I write my to-dos.
[image]

When I submit it, it appears below in a ***li*** element. There is an array and those strings are stored there and printed with ***map*** method.
[image]

There are circle checkboxes left of the writings and when I checked them a class is added to a ***li*** element which is ***"completed"***
[image]

Till here I have had no problem. Now there is a down arrow left of ***text input***. When I checked it I wanted it to check all checkboxes down below and add ***"completed"*** class to their ***li*** elements.  It is coded like:

```
<input className = "toggle-all" type = "checkbox"/>
        <label htmlFor = "toggle-all" >
        Mark all as complete
        </label>
```

[image]

And here is my App.js, two components. Footer is not important.

[image]

Main component, Footer is not important again.

[image]

Header component

[image]

And the component I am struggling with is the Section

[image]

I have tried a lot of things yet I couldn't find a solution. Might be too many images and explanations but I wanted to make it clear for everybody. I want to use usestate to track all checkboxes but if the solution is not possible like that I am okay with the other solutions.

4.11.22

I created this question 2 days ago. During these two days, I tried various codes yet I couldn't make them work the way I wanted.

Comment: I would suggest to treat the checkbox that marks everything as an undeterminate checkbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating `setTexts` as array of string set it as array of object. Where object can be like this:

```
let obj = {
  text: "todo item 1",
  ischecked: false
}

const [listItem, setListItem] = useState([])
```

when adding new items in list you can do like this:

```
setListItem([...listItem, {text: "something to do another list", ischecked: false}])
```

when checking individual item call method `onCheck(args)`:

```
const onCheck = (selectedItem) => {
  let updatedList = listItem.map((item) => {
     if(item.text === selectedItem.text){
       return {
        text: item.text,
        ischecked: true
       }
     }
     return item
  })
  setListItem([...updatedList])
}
```

And Finally to your questions answer. Once you click dropdown arrow call method `checkedAllToDoList()`:

```
const checkedAlToDoList = () => {
  let updatedList = listItem.map((item) => {
     return {
       text: item,
       ischecked: true
     }
  })
  setListItem([...updatedList])
}
```

> Note: complete the flow as which method should pass as a props on
> which components

Comment: It would be more better if you can add unique id to you new added object of item also. While checking list item if would be great to compare id instead of text as i have done in above code sample. cause item my repeat multiple times and which may leads you to check multiple item at once in single click. this is one of the worst case senario of above sample. to overcome use unique id for object list item.

Comment: Thank you, I did what I want with your help, this explanation enlighten me a lot.